# Image won't draw, Canvas+double Buffering+Buffered Image used

Tags: java, image, swing, canvas, jframe

Okay, so here's the deal: I'm trying to simply draw an object (in this case a tornado) onto my main canvas. I'm using JFrames, a canvas, a buffer strategy, and a buffered image to draw on. As far as I can figure I'm using the "game loop" correctly and from what I've been previously able to find my order of operations in the rendering is correct. Is there some thing I'm missing about the nature of using buffer strategies perhaps? I can't tell why i get just a grey screen.

Basically I'm trying to get this tornado program working using as many "proper" graphical and coding techniques as possible. Ultimately all I want is a little city that has a tornado moving through it, with each component existing as an object (the tornado, buildings, people, etc). However I find myself unable to continue util I can actually draw the blasted! The code below should show you whatever else you need to know, I'm fairly new to programming and this is a high school project, so any other pointers are welcome but **mostly I want to know why the tornado wont draw!**

I'm using eclipse, by the way. and so far I've followed these toutorials and posts to get where I am now:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/image/drawing-on-a-buffered-image/

**This is the main class:**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main {

    static BufferStrategy BuffStrat;
    static Thread t1;
    static BufferedImage backbuff;
    static JFrame mainframe;

    static Tornado tornado;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simulation();
    }


    public static void Setup() {
        mainframe = new JFrame("Tornado Ally");
        mainframe.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Canvas maincanvas = new Canvas();
        maincanvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        maincanvas.setSize(750, 600);

        mainframe.add(maincanvas);
        mainframe.pack();
        mainframe.setVisible(true);

        maincanvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        BuffStrat = maincanvas.getBufferStrategy();

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

        backbuff = gc.createCompatibleImage(750, 600, Transparency.BITMASK);
        tornado = new Tornado (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, backbuff);
    }

    public static void Simulation() {
        Setup();

        while (true) {
            Render();
            delay(10);
        }
    }

    public static void Render() {

        Graphics2D g = null; 

        g =  backbuff.createGraphics();

        g.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 750, 600);
        tornado.drawTornado(g);

        Graphics gI = BuffStrat.getDrawGraphics();
        gI.drawImage(backbuff, 0, 0, null);

        BuffStrat.show();
        gI.dispose();
        g.dispose();

    }

    public static void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Tornado Object:**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.geom.Dimension2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Tornado {

    int x, y, z;
    int mag;
    double velocity;
    Dimension2D hitbox;

    GraphicsConfiguration gc;
    Image t;
    BufferedImage backbuff;


    public Tornado(int x, int y, int z, int mag, double velocity, BufferedImage backbuff) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.mag = mag;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.backbuff = backbuff;

        {
            try {
                t = ImageIO.read(new File("Sprites.Tornado/TornadoFull.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }


    }

    public void drawTornado(Graphics2D g) {

        g.drawImage(t, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't ignore your exceptions, the image may not have being loaded

Comment: I've considered that, and I'm looking into that now, but so far I don't seem to be getting any exceptions unless I call upon a method of the Image object like for example "t.getWidth();" which causes a nullpointerexception. so I'm not sure what this indicates exactly...

Comment: Ah! didn't see your answer, nevermind! I'll look into what you've said now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing your code, it throw an exception because your code attempted to construct a `BufferStrategy` before the window had being resized.  Because the main window is using a `LayoutManager` a better solution would be to use something like...

```
//maincanvas.setSize(750, 600);
maincanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 600));
```

When you call `pack`, the window will be resized to accommodate the preferred size of it's child components...

You are also ignoring your exceptions when you load you image, so you won't even know if it hadn't loaded for some reason.  At the very least, you should be logging any exceptions...

For example...

```
try {
    t = ImageIO.read(new File("TSprites.Tornado/TornadoFull.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code suggests that the image is an external resource, if not (and it's built into the application), you would need to use `getClass().getResource("/TSprites.Tornado/TornadoFull.png")` instead of `new File(...)`...

You should also consider constructing your UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, for details, take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

For example, I changed your `main` method to look more like...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Simulation();
    }
});
```

And updated your `Simulation` method to execute the main loop within the context of another thread, for example...

```
public static void Simulation() {
    Setup();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Render();
                delay(10);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

You may also like to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) as it will make you code easier to read by others

Also, beware of the over use of `static`.  This can cause more problems then they solve if not used correctly...

Also, try and avoid the use of magic numbers, instead, use values you know, for example...

Instead of...

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, 750, 600);
```

Try using...

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, backbuff.getWidth(), backbuff.getHeight());
```

Comment: Changing "new file" to "getClass().getResource()" fixed my problem! but I will definitely look into your and implement your other suggestions. Thank you very very much.